# wrap dictionary for readability?

Tags: c#, dictionary, readability

I'm building a translator that saves the translation in a dictionary where the first string is an identifier and the seconds string is the translated string.

It seems to me that the dictionary syntax is not very readable so I'm thinking about wrapping my dictionary like

```
class Translation : Dictionary<string,string>{}
```

and then also the keyvaluepair like

```
class SingleTranslation : KeyValuePair<string,string>
```

But the KeyValuePair class is sealed (can not be inherited). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make my dictionary more readable?

My biggest worry is when I have to iterate over the dictionary with

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in _translation)
{
    string whatever = kvp.Value;
    do stuff...
    if(kvp.key)
        do stuff..
}
```

I could of course create a string in the foreach that is called Identifier and set it equal to kvp.key. But I would prefer something like

```
foreach(SingleTranslation singleTranslation in _translation)
{
    singleTranslation.Identifier ... do stuff...
}
```

Comment: "Wrapping" - that sounds like composition. You could create a class backed by a dictionary and expose the features you want through the underlying dict

Comment: If you use `var` much of this noise goes away. `foreach (var kvp in _translation)` ... and is `Identifier` much better than `Key` that anyone else reading your code will understand? Also why are you iterating over the whole dictionary? If you access pattern is primarily sequential just use a `List<SingleTranslation>`. If you are really concerned about size and speed you could use a TernaryTree instead which is what many word-dictionaries use.

Comment: What does "more readable" mean to you?

Comment: @Dennis Kuypers: sure thing, with some extra work I could make it work with an iterator, and overload the [] operators..

Comment: @Ian Mercer: I agree that key and identifier are interchangable words and both of them are good in this case.
I'm iterating over the whole dictionary because I'm sending it to an embedded software unit.. and I think that I the lookup functionallity will be handy in the future, and that's why I choose a dictionary

Comment: @ Enigmativity yesterday: more readable to me means that you need to spend less time looking at the code to understand what it means. for example returning a dictionary from a function doesn't always tell anything about the content of the dictionary. While creating an object based on a dictionary or inheriting a dictionary can with it's name give the user information about the objects purpose

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Either use `Dictionnary` directly for complete access or use composition if you want more control.

Also use `var` in foreach loops. There is no value in defining a custom type for that (and it should not even works as you try to convert `KeyValuePair` to a derived class. And by the way, this is one reason why it is sealed.

If you really want to use custom types, and do not want to write much custom code, then maybe something like that could works for you:

```
class Translation
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> Data { get } = new Dictionary<string,string>;
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Translation t; // Fill some data...
foreach (var item in t.Data) { … }
```

That way, you can ensure that you don't pass the improper dictionary to functions as you use distinct types for each case:

```
void DisplayTranslation(Translation t) { … }
```

If you want, you could improve your `Translation` class so that it does not expose the internal dictionary but expose appropriate members, properties and interfaces for the desired usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use something other than a dictionary, like a class that inherits from List and then add an indexer on it so you could still use syntax like `translations["myIndex"]`. The code below could be optimized, but you can get the idea.

```
public class Translations : List<SingleTranslation>
{
    public SingleTranslation this[string identifier]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Identifier == identifier);
        }
        set
        {
            SingleTranslation translation = this.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Identifier == identifier);
            if (translation == null)
            {
                this.Add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                translation.Value = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SingleTranslation
{
    public SingleTranslation(string identifier, string value)
    {
        Identifier = identifier;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Translations translations = new Translations();
        translations.Add(new SingleTranslation("hello", "hola"));
        translations.Add(new SingleTranslation("day", "día"));
        foreach(SingleTranslation translation in translations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", translation.Identifier, translation.Value);
        }

        translations["hello"].Value = "salut";
        translations["day"].Value = "jour";

        foreach(SingleTranslation translation in translations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", translation.Identifier, translation.Value);
        }                
    }
}
```

A working example of this is in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CY03QS):

Answer (score 1):

If readability is simply your issue, you could alias it within the namespace declaration.

```
using SingleTranslation = KeyValuePair<string,string>;
```